How do you remove EXIF/metadata with native Powershell?
The below code displays:
Prior: 271 272 274 282 283 296 305 306 531 33432 33437 34850 34855 36864 36867 36868 37121 37122 37377 37378 37379 37380 37381 37383 37385 37386 37500 40960 40961 40962 40963 20545 20546 41486 41487 41 488 41495 41728 41729 20507 20515 20521 20525 20526 20528 513 514 20537 20625 20624
then:
After: 
so it seems to be removing the EXIF/metadata, but when I save the file and compare non_2, to _2 file, with the likes of https://pics.io/photo-metadata-viewer, I see exactly the same metadata. If I remove metadata using this tool, save, and reopen it in the aforementioned tool, FAR less metadata exists.
What am I missing that causes the presumed removal of metadata with the code prior to save, not actually making it into the saved file?
NOTE: This is a proof of principle script, and not meant to be the most efficient coding.
$FullPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Fujifilm_FinePix6900ZOOM.jpg"

$FS = [System.IO.File]::Open($FullPath,3)

$Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($FS, $false, $false)

$PropertyItems = $Image.PropertyIdList
write-host "Prior: $PropertyItems"

foreach($propertyItem in $propertyItems)
{
  $image.removepropertyitem($propertyItem)
}
$JpegCodec = [system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo]::getimageencoders() | where-object { $_.MimeType -eq "image/jpeg" }
$EncoderParams = new-object system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameters
$Encoder = [system.drawing.imaging.encoder]::quality
$EncoderParam = new-object system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter($Encoder, 100)
$EncoderParams.param[0] = $EncoderParam
$FullPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Fujifilm_FinePix6900ZOOM_2.jpg"
$Image.save($FullPath,$JpegCodec,$EncoderParams)

$PropertyItems = $image.PropertyIdList
write-host "After: $PropertyItems"

$Image.dispose | out-null

$FS.close() | out-null


this is a problem 100%: $Image.Dispose, should be $Image.Dispose(). The former will only get you the method overload definitions instead of actually invoking the method. also .Dispose is a void method always, so Out-Null is not needed at all.

@SantiagoSquarzon Changed, and yes can now remove out-null. Thanks. So many examples of code online not in Powershell, but .NET, or maybe C that it is hard to remove what does and doesn't need (). However no change in outputted file.

No worries, in .NET (C# and PowerShell) to invoke a method you must always use () just for ref

I know you don't want external tools, but ExifTool can replace your whole code by one line: exiftool -All= Fujifilm_FinePix6900ZOOM.jpg, while not re-encoding your image and just removing all metadata (Exif, ICC and IPTC). Not sure if .NET even reads ICC and IPTC into the properties... Be aware, there can also be technical metadata, that cannot be removed as it belongs to the image format. E. g. BMP stores the resolution, which cannot be removed as it will corrupt the file.

@stackprotector I can't consider that, because I need this to be a 1 file solution. Hence, know of any way to embed an exe in Powershell files, that could be written out and run when the PS is run? I know that is super suspicious to virus scanners, but sans anyone able to help me figure out why the above code isn't working, that seems like a viable alternative. Fine with technical details being kept b.t.w

Why does it need to be a 1 file solution? (asking out of curiosity in case there is a solution to that issue as well that could help you here).

@ChadBaldwin So that I don't have to support those I provide the script to, to make sure the file is there, in the right place, etc.
